# Windows 7: Set Different Language/Keyboard Default for Different Users?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I have to share "my" computer at the office with another user that works a different shift. Some of the work I do requires the use of accented letters, so I prefer to use the US-International keyboard. The person who uses this computer on the other shift does not have this need, and the standard US keyboard is proper for him. How, if at all, can I make the US-International keyboard *my* default, while leaving the standard US keyboard the default for other users of this computer?

Edit: This is specifically about setting the default input method (keyboard layout) on a *per-user* basis. I want everything *for me* to default to **US-International**, but for the other user, retain the default of **English-United States**.

Answer (score 0):

How about having the language bar docked in the taskbar? The steps to do this are 1) search for 'change keyboard' in the Start Menu search box, 2) click on 'Change keyboards or other input methods', 3) click on 'Change keyboards' button in the 'Region and Language' window, 4) In the Language Bar tab of the 'Text Services and Input Languages' click on 'Docked in the taskBar'  Once that's set up, the default keyboard shortcuts for switching between languages is  'Left Alt + Shift' but that can be changed in the 'Advanced Key Settings' tab of the 'Text Services and Input Languages' window.  It's described in more detail on [this page](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-keyboard-input-language) especially at the bottom: http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-change-keyboard-input-language

Comment: This answer can be improved by giving summary of steps required from the link. As of current form, if the link break, this answer will be invalidated and deleted.

Comment: I'm quite skilled at using the language bar and setting up languages and input methods; the issue here is strictly and specifically setting per-user defaults - I want everything to assume US-International unless I specifically set otherwise, but the other user of my computer needs to be left to default to the regular English-United States keyboard.

Comment: Okay, I think what you're saying is that you want to know if there's a way not to have to use the language bar, or even type the keyboard shortcut? Perhaps that could be done with a startup script that modifies the user settings upon login, or maybe a .bat file which executes upon start up in each account.  I don't know right off the bat how to do that, but perhaps framing the question that way will get you the help you need.